# Can these conditions sufficiently solve an equation involving absolute values

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an equation $$|x-152|+|y-152|+|z-145|+|w-145|=340$$, I need to find out the values of $x,y,z,w$. I know this can not be solve uniquely. But I have other constraints also, which I think are sufficient to solve the equation uniquely. But I do not know whether my constraints can be applied to a generic case. Here is what I did to solve this particular equation. The unique value that I needed was $(29,55,59,111)$. The first constraint that I have is $$0\leq x,y,z,w\leq 255,~~x+y+z+w=254$$. Apart from this  I have two more information. I give the two  highest modulus say i know that the highest modulus is $|x-152|=123$ and $|y-152|=93$. Now solving the first modulus gives $x=29,275$, now i ignore $x=275$ because of the first constraint. Then i solve the second modulus $|y-152|=93$ which gives me $y=59,245$, i discard $y=245$ because of the constrain that $x+y+z+w=254$ since already we are sure that $x=29$, hence we get $y=59$. Now, we are left with the equation $$|z-145|+|w-145|=124$$ and the equation $$y+z=166$$, this gives us $z=55, w=111$

My question is will this strategy work with a generic case?

Can any constraint be relaxed and still achieve a unique solution?

Instead of knowing the $2$ highest modulus, I think I should know that modulus whose sum of the centre and radius should exceed $255$, for instance in this case $152+123>255$

Comment: Are  x,y,z,w  real numbers?

Comment: Do they have to be integers?

Comment: Yes Jan they are integers

Answer (score 0):

> This is not a 'real' answer but it was too big for a comment.

Well, I just coded something in Mathematica:

```
In[1]:=Solve[{Abs[x - 152] + Abs[y - 152] + Abs[z - 145] + Abs[w - 145] == 
   340, w + x + y + z == 254, 
  0 <= w <= 255 && 0 <= x <= 255 && 0 <= y <= 255 && 
   0 <= z <= 255}, {w, x, y, z}, PositiveIntegers]
```

And it gave me round about 1925505 solutions (the solutions I show downhere they are not all the solutions, if you want all the solutions that Mathematica found, you can contact me):

```
Out[1]={w -> 1, x -> 1, y -> 107, z -> 145}, {w -> 1, x -> 1, y -> 108, 
 z -> 144}, {w -> 145, x -> 106, y -> 2, z -> 1}, {w -> 145, x -> 107, y -> 1, z -> 1}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I wanted help with a theoretical justification of whether my method is correct or not

Comment: @Upstart Yes I understand, that is why I posted it as a comment instead of an answer. But as I stated there are a lot of solutions, round about 1925505.